# Как взять подстроку с помощью Substring() от начала

Tags: java

Как взять ту часть, которую отрезали. Например:

```
String s="hello java";
String sub=s.substring(5);
```

И когда это выводим, в консоли будет `java`. А как сделать, чтоб в консоли вывод был `hello`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sub = s.substring(0, 5);
```